# Gstreamer custom plugin to read data (YUV) from file?

Tags: linux, video, gstreamer, video-processing, multimedia

Ok, let me explain you first that why i need a custom filter to read from a yuv file or buffer.

We are working on a camera interface and its driver is not V4L2 compliant. So we tweaked it and got a frame in YUV format out of it. Currently I have to access that frame with my custom gstreamer plugin.

so for proof of concept I am trying to read data from a YUV file and try to display it.

1) I converted .mp4 file into .yuv format as follows

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x480 -r 30 rawvideo.yuv
```

2) I played the yuv file successfully using gstreamer pipes as follow

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=rawvideo.yuv ! videoparse width=640 height=480 framerate=30/1 ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

3) I made a custom plugin , named it **myfilter** and tweaked it with code as below to read from yuv file

```
FILE *V_fp = NULL;

GstBuffer * read_from_videofile(void)
{

   GstBuffer *filedata;

   if(V_fp == NULL)
   {
       V_fp = fopen("/home/linux/rawvideo.yuv","rb");
   }

   //file open
   if(NULL != V_fp)
   {
       //Get Size of Data
       int size = 24;

       //allocate memory
       filedata = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL,size,NULL);

       //clear memory
       gst_buffer_memset(filedata, 0, '\0', size);

       //fill data into the buffer
       if(size != gst_buffer_fill(filedata, 0,V_fp,size))
       {
           fclose(V_fp);
           return NULL;
       }

   }

   return filedata;
}

/* chain function
 * this function does the actual processing
 */
static GstFlowReturn
gst_my_filter_chain (GstPad * pad, GstObject * parent, GstBuffer * buf)
{
  GstMyFilter *filter;

  filter = GST_MYFILTER (parent);

  GstFlowReturn ret = GST_FLOW_ERROR;

  if (filter->silent == FALSE)
      g_print ("I'm plugged, therefore I'm in.\n");


  GstBuffer *data = read_from_videofile();

  if(NULL != data)
  {
      /* just push out the incoming buffer without touching it */
      //return gst_pad_push (filter->srcpad, buf);
      ret = gst_pad_push (filter->srcpad,data);
      if(GST_FLOW_OK == ret)
          g_print("Data pushed successfully\n");
      else
          g_print("Error in pushing Data\n");
  }
  else
  {
      g_print("Data read failed\n");
  }

  return ret;
}
```

After this i added my plugin to gstreamer pipe

```
gst-launch-1.0 fakesrc ! myfilter ! videoparse width=640 height=480 framerate=30/1 ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

But it is showing video like this

[image: gst-launch not showing video]

Can anyone help me to find my mistake ? I am totally new with gstreamer.

Note:- I am using fakesrc as my driving source because my custom plugin is not yet coded to work independently.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to pass your FILE pointer to `gst_buffer_fill`, you need to read it into memory first if you want to use that method.

Comment: @mpr , can you please elaborate what should i do ? Cause as you suggested i filled a memory with my FILE pointer and  then copied it to gstbuffer. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll want to read up on functions like `fread` and `mmap`.  A FILE pointer is a pointer to an open file descriptor--not the data in the file.

Comment: @mrp,  I does as you suggested open the file in O_RDWR mode, map the file data into memory using mmap and read functions and then copied this memory to gstbuffer. Now its shows a "black" screen. So is that anyhting else i can do ?? Guyz please help am stuck up at this point.

Comment: What @mrp means as per my understanding is (do this step by step on an already created GstBuffer) 1) GstMapInfo info; 2) gst_buffer_map (buf, &info, GST_MAP_WRITE); 3) fread(info.data,1,size,V_fp); 4)  gst_buffer_unmap (buf, &info);

Answer (score 1):

Done as follows.

```
GstBuffer * read_from_videofile(void)
{

   GstBuffer *filedata;

   if(V_fp == NULL)
   {   
       V_fp = fopen(READ_LOCATION_VIDEO,"rb");
   }   

   if(NULL != V_fp)
   {   
       //Add this IF contition to play video continuously in loop
       if(feof(V_fp))
       {
           fseek(V_fp,0,SEEK_SET);
       }

       int size = 307200;// (640 * 480)
       void *data = (void *) malloc(size * sizeof(void));

       size = fread(data,1,size,V_fp);

       //Creates a new buffer that wraps the given data . The memory will be freed with g_free and will be marked writable.
       filedata = gst_buffer_new_wrapped(data,size);

       //free(data);
   }

   return filedata;
}
```

After that i ran the following command on terminal

```
gst-launch-1.0 fakesrc ! myfilter ! videoparse width=640 height=480 framerate=30/1 ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

This gives me the following output

[image: gst video]

The code can be found in this [myfilesrc.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5oeolfpsiowai47/myfilesrc.zip?dl=0) file. This code is not neat and clean as it should be. But an engineer can easily understand it.

Comment: I will try to make this plugin independent of "fakesrc" and post the whole code.

Comment: Sure~, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @fizzbuzz Will upload within a day. And update the answer also.

Comment: @fizzbuzz find the code attached. If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Will have a look asap, Thanks